Laravel Vue/Inertia.js seting value for an image input
I have a file input for uploading images
<input class="w-2/3" type="file" id="image" name="image" @input="form.image = $event.target.files[0]" accept="image/*">

It works for creating a new model instance, but what I'm trying to do is use it in an edit page. As such, when editing a model that already has an image, this image needs to already be input when the page loads.
I'm not even sure how to access the file from the storage in the appropriate manner (should I import it in Vue, or send it as a prop from the controller?), much less how to actually upload it rather than just setting it's URL as the input's value.
Any advice would be appreciated.
